# Java SWT Selecting Table Row

Tags: java, swt

I have a problem with selecting the `Table` row. Always when I click on the `CCombo` the row is not selected. (See  the system.output is 0 or -1).How can i select a row in a SWT table. I want to get the row at a `SelectionListener`. Thanks for answers. An example is following:

```
public class FrameVerwaltung  {

    private Display display;
    private Shell shell;
    private Table tableLoc;
    private String[] colNames = { "Name",  "ToDo",};
    private static FrameVerwaltung frame;
    private org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color colorYellow;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        frame = new FrameVerwaltung();
    }

    public FrameVerwaltung() {
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);
        FormLayout layout = new FormLayout();
        shell.setLayout(layout);
        colorYellow = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW);

        pSetTable();

        shell.setText("");
        shell.pack();
        //shell.setSize(1500, 1000);
        shell.open();
        shell.setMaximized(true);

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
        }

        display.dispose();  
    }


    private void pSetTable() {
        tableLoc = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        GridData gridData= new GridData();

        tableLoc.setLinesVisible(true);
        tableLoc.setHeaderVisible(true);

        pSetTableColumn();
        //*table.setToolTipText("Eine Tabelle");
        psetTableRows();
    }

    private void pSetTableColumn() {
        TableColumn[] cols = new TableColumn[colNames.length];
        int[] order = new int[colNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < colNames.length; i++) {

            TableColumn tc = new TableColumn(tableLoc, SWT.BORDER);

            tc.setText(colNames[i]);
            switch (i){
            case 0:
                tc.setWidth(200);
                break;
            case 1:
                tc.setWidth(50);
                break;
            }
            tc.setResizable(true);

            //tc.setMoveable(true);
            cols[i] = tc;
            order[i] = i;

        }
    }

    private void psetTableRows() {
        for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
            TableItem itemTmp = new TableItem(tableLoc, SWT.BORDER);

            itemTmp.setText(0,String.valueOf(k));
            pSetTableRowToDo(itemTmp);  
        }
    }

    private void pSetTableRowToDo(TableItem itemIn) {
        TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(tableLoc);
        CCombo comboboxAction = new CCombo(tableLoc, SWT.BORDER | SWT.CHECK | SWT.MULTI
                | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        comboboxAction.setText("=");
        comboboxAction.add("=");
        comboboxAction.add(">");
        comboboxAction.add("<");
        comboboxAction.add("?");
        comboboxAction.add("x");

        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(comboboxAction,itemIn,1);
        editor = new TableEditor(tableLoc);
        comboboxAction.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i=0;i<7;i++) {     
                    CCombo ccoboTmp = (CCombo) arg0.getSource();

                    TableItem[] tableItem = tableLoc.getSelection();
                    System.out.println(tableItem.length);
                    System.out.println(tableLoc.getSelectionIndex());
                }
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**
One way of selecting the table row on selection of CCombo is passing the row index to `pSetTableRowToDo()` when creating each row and then in `comboboxAction.addSelectionListener()` do `tableLoc.setSelection(rowToSelect)` which works perfect like below.

```
private void psetTableRows() {
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 7; rowIndex++) {
            TableItem itemTmp = new TableItem(tableLoc, SWT.BORDER);

            itemTmp.setText(0, String.valueOf(rowIndex));
            pSetTableRowToDo(itemTmp, rowIndex);
        }
    }


private void pSetTableRowToDo(TableItem itemIn, int rowIndex) {
        TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(tableLoc);
        CCombo comboboxAction = new CCombo(tableLoc, SWT.BORDER | SWT.CHECK | SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        comboboxAction.setText("=");
        comboboxAction.add("=");
        comboboxAction.add(">");
        comboboxAction.add("<");
        comboboxAction.add("?");
        comboboxAction.add("x");

        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(comboboxAction, itemIn, 1);
        editor = new TableEditor(tableLoc);
        comboboxAction.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                tableLoc.setSelection(rowIndex);
                tableLoc.forceFocus();
                System.out.println("Selected Table Row Index: " +tableLoc.getSelectionIndex());
            }

        });
    }
```

**Solution 2:**
Another approach is to get the index of tableItem and set the selection to that index which works perfect like below. You might want to use `tableLoc.forceFocus();` so that the selected row will be focused.

```
private void pSetTableRowToDo(TableItem itemIn) {
        TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(tableLoc);
        CCombo comboboxAction = new CCombo(tableLoc, SWT.BORDER | SWT.CHECK | SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        comboboxAction.setText("=");
        comboboxAction.add("=");
        comboboxAction.add(">");
        comboboxAction.add("<");
        comboboxAction.add("?");
        comboboxAction.add("x");

        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(comboboxAction, itemIn, 1);
        editor = new TableEditor(tableLoc);
        comboboxAction.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                int indexOf = tableLoc.indexOf(itemIn);
                tableLoc.setSelection(indexOf);
                tableLoc.forceFocus();
                System.out.println("Selected Table Row Index: " + tableLoc.getSelectionIndex());
            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `pSetTableRowToDo` method, you pass in the `TableItem` that the `CCombo` is added to, so in your `SelectionListener` you can leverage this by calling:

`tableLoc.indexOf(itemIn);` (See: [`Table.indexOf(TableItem)`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Table.html#indexOf-org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem-))

Note that you will need to make the `itemIn` parameter to `pSetTableRowToDo` `final`, but this isn't a problem at all, and is actually preferable.

With that index, you can then call [`tableLoc.setSelection(int)`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Table.html#setSelection-int-).